# How to assign weights to different columns using SQL?

Tags: sql, weighted, weighted-average

I have a data set with the following headers: `product, sales, material_1, material_2, material_3, style_1, style_2, style_3`.

Based on this data set, I need to find the most successful materials and style based on sales. The column `material_1` should be weighted *3, `material_2` should be weighted *2, and `material_3` should be weighted *1. The same goes for the style columns.

So, basically, I need to somehow weight each column differently and then multiply it by the sales of that product but I am having trouble figuring out how to do so. Based off how I see the data, Cotton material and Modern style should be the most successful outcome.

```
Product Sales   material_1  material_2  material_3  style_1     style_2 style_3
A   2629715     Cotton      Synthetic   Silk        modern      vintage 
B   2527075     Cotton      leather     Synthetic   modern      Young   
C   678434      Cotton      Synthetic   Silk        modern      Punk    
D   735281      Cotton      leather     Wool        modern      vintage 
E   439256      Cotton      Silk        Denim       young       
F   353630      Silk        Denim       Cotton      Punk        
G   579318      Wool        leather     Cotton      vintage     Young   Chic
H   505876      Cotton      leather     Wool        modern      young   
I   325997      Cotton      Silk                    contemporary        modern  
J   274980      Cotton      Silk                    young       
K   280422      Denim                               young       Punk    Punk
L   293283      Synthetic   Cotton      modern      
M   217215      Cotton      Silk        young       modern  
N   306687      Synthetic   Wool        Cotton      modern      vintage 
O   232490      Cotton      Silk        modern      young   
P   216559      Synthetic   Cotton      modern      
Q   219996      Denim       Cotton      young
```

Comment: The moment you have multiple columns of similar type, it smells of a really bad design. You should only have one column for material, and different material values for a particular product should be in separate rows with their priority order.

Comment: Please show the results that you want and the method you want to use for weighting.  As written, your question is just too broad.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have specified the weighting further in the question now. In theory I just want to be able to see what the single most popular material is as well as the most popular style. Based on just looking at the data, cotton and modern should be the most successful.

Answer (score 0):

Some "expected output" would be helpful, but not having that, here is one way to think about it:

```sql
WITH materials(weight, material) AS (
  SELECT 3 AS weight, material_1 AS material from mytable 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, material_2 from mytable 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, material_3 from mytable
) 

SELECT material, SUM(weight) AS Weighted_Value
FROM materials
GROUP BY material
```

Here's what it does:

1. Move all of your `material` columns into a single column so you can process them a little easier
2. Assign the weights you specified to each column
3. Adds up the weights associated with each material from each sale, grouped together by material

You can use similar logic for the `style` fields.  Give it a try and let me know if it works for you.